# Java: ClassNotFoundException - Something to do with input file?

Tags: java

Getting the following errors in Apache Nutch/Solr:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:177)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: opennlp/tools/sentdetect/SentenceDetector
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.nutch.plugin.Extension.getExtensionInstance(Extension.java:160)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingFilters.<init>(IndexingFilters.java:69)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.configure(IndexerMapReduce.java:62)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:315)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:250)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
    ... 26 more
2012-04-24 13:59:18,713 ERROR solr.SolrIndexer - java.io.IOException: Job failed!
```

I modified a filter class called BasicIndexingFilter.java to use OpenNLP's SentenceDetector class. Relevant part of BasicIndexingFilter.java:

```
SentenceDetector sentenceDetector = null;

        InputStream modelIn = null;
        try {
            // Loading sentence detection model
            modelIn = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/models/sentdetect/en-sent.bin");
            final SentenceModel sentenceModel = new SentenceModel(modelIn);
            modelIn.close();

            sentenceDetector = new SentenceDetectorME(sentenceModel);

        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            LOG.info("Model input error");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (modelIn != null) {
                try {
                    modelIn.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {} // oh well!
            }
        }
```

I've added this to the build.xml file:

```
 <property name="lib.dir"     value="lib"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>
```

It compiles fine now, but I get the runtime errors. I'm new to Java but I'm guessing it has something to do with the model file I'm trying to load in:

```
modelIn = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/models/sentdetect/en-sent.bin");
```

The `opennlp-tools-1.5.0.jar` for the SentenceDetector class is in my `./lib folder` and the model file `en-sent.bin` is in `.lib/models/sentdetect`. The BasicIndexingFilter class is somewhere else and it's all running from Nutch's bin file.

Is it a problem with pointing to the model file or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `maxent 3.0.0 jar` file on your classpath. If you do have this then try adding [opennlp-tools-1.5.1-incubating.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/opennlp/opennlp-tools/1.5.1-incubating/opennlp-tools-1.5.1-incubating.jar) to your libs.

Comment: I have `maxent 3.0.0 jar` in my ./lib folder with the rest of the OpenNLP .jar's and the following the the build.xml file for BasicIndexingFilter.java: `<property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/> <path id="classpath"> <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*/.jar"/> </path>`

Comment: The BasicIndexingFilter.java seems to build fine with Ant.

Comment: See edited with a link to `opennlp-tools-1.5.1-incubating.jar` which hold `SentenceDetector` as reported not found by the exception .

Comment: I already had the following .jar's in my ./lib: opennlp-tools-1.5.0.jar, maxent-3.0.0.jar, jwnl-1.3.3.jar, and trove-3.0.2.jar.

Comment: If you expand the jar `opennlp-tools-1.5.0.jar`, can you locate `opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetector.class`? if not relace it with the incubating version or 1.5.1 version instead of 1.5.0.

Comment: OK. Figured it out. So in Nutch there's a `src` folder, a `build` folder, and a `runtime` folder. I had the jar's in all the folders except the `runtime` one, which is of course where I was running Nutch from. Now they're there and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an app from a jar file, add a Manifest.mf to it. Inside the manifest insert the jar files that you want to be added to your classpath. Follow instructions here:
http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html#applications
Hope this can help you.